correlation between bid/ask prices and bid/ask sizes to realized volatility
I am trying to understand the effect of correlation between bid price and ask size with realized volatility (called targe_vol). Similarly, correlation between ask price and bid size with realized volatility. This is shown in the graph below for data of 112 stocks. Does this picture make sense? When the bid size and ask price are both high then price will have to move towards ask price thereby increasing volatitliy. similarly, when bid size is high/(low) and ask price is small/(large) then price move is smaller/(no trade happens) and real. vol. should be smaller too. By this logic, I should see a positive correlation of bid price and ask size correlation to real. vol. Why is this inverted?
There seems to be a general pattern here because it's negatively correlated for most stocks.
The formula for realized volatility is as follows:





It seems that you are using the Optiver Kaggle Challenge data right? In that case it might be useful to point out that the target is "realized volatility computed over the 10 minute window" and "no overlap between feature and target data". This should give others more context to answer your question.

@autoencoder yes correct. Hmm however, the first 10 minute window's realized volatitliy is highly correlated with the 2nd 10 minute window's realized volatility so we can naively assume that the feature "overlaps" with the target! Could you please explain now?
